# gpg: decrypt_message failed: Unexpected error

Tags: gpg

i am trying to decrypt a text with a valid private key that is imported into my instance and is in working condition. the key decrypts any other text but this particular one results in this error message.

> gpg: decrypt_message failed: Unexpected error

i did a `--list-packets` to ensure that what I have is in fact the key that text was encrypted for. i tried the same steps in two different fresh distros (fedora and ubuntu)
and it resulted in the same error. i am not sure where to go from here. would anyone have any ideas what might be wrong here?

thanks!

Comment: Assuming encrypted data in `file.gpg`, check output of `gpg -vvv --decrypt file.gpg`

Answer (score 1):

I get that error message when I try decrypting something that is not encrypted. For example, an exported public or private key. `--list-packets` works perfectly and identifies the public key as such, and helpfully provides the keyid, but it is not the keyid of the recipient that the message is keyed to, it is the actual unencrypted keyid of the key that is the object and the only content of the file.

Hope this helps.